# How do I search for items in a list like the function "LIKE" in SQL for Python?

Tags: python

I'm just going to put this in words as I am still learning how to write in Python.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Let's have an example where I want to search for a specific number in a list with numbers from 1 to 10. When a specific number **is** on the list, it would execute/perform a function.

Example:

```
if x == 1:
    print("Do something")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*When a specific number is on the list :*

```
if num in my_list:
     #do something
```

Example with your list

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> if 3 in x:
...     print("3 found")
... 
3 found
```